# Prove the set of subsequential limits is an interval

Tags: calculus, limits

> Let $\{ a_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a bounded sequence such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n-a_{n+1}=0$. Prove the set of subsequential limits is an interval.

My thoughts:

$a_n$ is bounded $\Rightarrow \exists M>0\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}:|a_n|<M$

So I'm trying to prove that the set of subsequential limits is $(-M,M)$.

I understand that I need to set the right $\epsilon>0$ for the limit given and work with it, but having hard time formalizing it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is a partial limit?

Comment: Do you really think that, just knowing that $|a_n|\lt M,$ you should be able to prove that the set of "partial limits" (whatever those might be) is $(-M,M)?$ The trouble is, if $|a_n|\lt M$ for all $n,$ then also $|a_n|\lt10M$ for all $n.$ Do you think you can prove that the set of "partial limits" is equal to $(-M,M)$ and also to $(-10M,10M)?$

Comment: Sorry for that, will fix to subsequential limit.

Comment: By the way, what's your definition of an "interval"? Is $\{0\}$ an interval?

Comment: @bof No, it has to be set of real numbers that lies between two real numbers.

Comment: What interval do you get if $a_n$ happens to be a **convergent** sequence, say, if $a_n=\frac1n?$

Comment: If $a_n$ is a convergent sequence, say $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L,$ then $a_n$ is a bounded sequence, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n-a_{n+1})=L-L=0.$ But every subsequence converges to $L.$

Comment: I think the correct conclusion should be that the set of subsequential limits is either **a single point** or an interval. By the way, I believe the interval has to be a closed interval, but it looks like you weren't asked to prove that.

Comment: Do you know what $\lim\inf_{n\to\infty}a_n$ and $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}a_n$ mean? And do you know that they both exist if the sequence is bounded?

Comment: @bof Yes, I do.

Comment: I believe the interval you're looking for is $[b,c]$ where $b=\lim\inf_{n\to\infty}a_n$ and $c=\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}a_n.$ What you have to show, then, is that given any number $L\in[b,d]$ you can construct a subsequence which converges to $L.$

Comment: @bof The set of subsequential limits is $\bigcap_p \overline{\{u_{n+p}|\; n\geq 1\}}$ hence closed.

Comment: @bof How can I construct such subsequence?

Comment: See also: [Let $a = \liminf x_n$, $b = \limsup x_n$. If $\lim (x_{n+1} - x_n) = 0$ then every element of $(a,b)$ is a subsequential limit of $(x_n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2666730).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that with $b=\liminf{a_n}$ and $c=\limsup{a_n}$, we have that the set $M$ of limits of (convergent) subsequences of $a_n$ is included in $[b,c]$. If $b=c$, the sequence $a_n$ is convergent and we are done. Now suppose $b<c$ and let $b <u<v<c$. The sets $E=\{n; a_n<u\}$ and $F=\{n; a_n>v\}$ are infinite(because there are subsequences of $a_n$ converging to $b$ and $c$). If there is only a finite number of $n$ such that $u\leq a_n\leq v$, then we can find a sequence $n_k\in E$ with $1+n_k\in F$. But then $a_{1+n_k}-a_{n_k}\geq v-u>0$, a contradiction as $a_{1+n_k}-a_{n_k}\to 0$ if $k\to \infty$. Hence we can find a subsequence $a_{n_m}=u_m$ of $a_n$ such that $v\geq u_m\geq u$. Then $u_m$ has a convergent subsequence, say to $L$, and clearly $L\in M$ We have shown that the closed subset $M$ is dense in $[b,c]$, hence it is equal to $[b,c]$.