# Let $a = \liminf x_n$, $b = \limsup x_n$. If $\lim (x_{n+1} - x_n) = 0$ then every element of $(a,b)$ is a subsequential limit of $(x_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

I'm fixing an arbitrary $x$ in $a<x<b$ and I must prove that $x$ is the limit of a subsequence of $(x_n)$.
I have a theorem that says that $x$ is a subsequential limit of a sequence $(x_n)$ iff every interval $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$ containts infinitely many terms of $(x_n)$. I also know that $a$ and $b$ are the smallest and largest subsequential limits of $(x_n)$. 
I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Is $(x_{n})$ assumed to be bounded? (so neither of $a,b$ can be $\pm\infty$)

Comment: @DanielLittlewood The exercise doesn't say anything about it being bounded so maybe the proof is divided in two cases, one for when it's bounded and one for when it's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sketch:** Fix $c\in(a,b)$. We will show that for every $\epsilon >0$, small enough, there are infinite many $x_n \in (c-\epsilon, c+\epsilon)$.

Find $n_0$ such that $|x_{n+1} - x_n| <\epsilon$ for all $n\geq n_0$.

Since $\liminf x_n =a $ we can find $n_1 > n_0$ such that $x_{n_1} < c-\epsilon$.

Since $\limsup x_n =b $ we can find $n_2 > n_1$ such that $x_{n_2} > c+\epsilon$.

Therefore, at time $n_1$ $x_{n_1}$ is on the left of $(c-\epsilon, c+\epsilon)$ and at time $n_2$ $x_{n_2}$ is on the right of $(c-\epsilon, c+\epsilon)$. Since the sequence makes jumps of at most length $\epsilon$ there must be a time $\tilde{n}\in (n_1,n_2)$ such that $x_\tilde{n} \in (c-\epsilon, c+\epsilon)$.

We can repeat this procedure to find infinite many $x_n \in (c-\epsilon, c+\epsilon)$, hence $c$ is a limit point of $x_n$.

Comment: Why is $x_{n_1} < c-\epsilon$?. I get that if $n_1 > n_0$ then $-\epsilon < x_{n_1+ 1} - x_{n_1} <\epsilon$. I'm just starting to understand the definition of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$. I know that $\liminf x_n = a$ means that $a$ is the least subsequential limit of $(x_n)$, or that $a$ is the sup of the sequence consisting of inf's of all tail-ends of $(x_n)$. I don't understand how $c$ relates to any of this.

Comment: @user397146 The $\epsilon$ is chosen such that $c-\epsilon >a$. So if there is no such $n_1$, this would mean that for all $n \geq n_0$ we must have $x_n \geq c-\epsilon>a$. Therefore, $a$ wouldn't be a subsequential limit of $x_n$.